# Is there anyway to improve this query computational cost?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.1 on my own machine for this database.

I have this database of transactions. Entire database is around 100 million rows x 30 columns. Transactions span over the past four years.

For this query, there are three relevant columns:

- transaction timestamp which is rounded to the nearest 15 minutes
- vendor ID
- transaction amount (revenue)

I am interested in returning output of four columns such as the below image (sorry for the link - don't have enough rep to imbed images yet:

[image]

The output is the count of transactions during that specific timestamp, the count of unique active vendors in the past 60 minutes, and the hourly revenue over the past 60 minutes.

Below is the code I used to try to accomplish this.

```
SELECT transaction_timestamp,
   COUNT(transaction_timestamp) AS "transaction_timestamp",
   (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT vendor_id)
    FROM transactions_db
    WHERE transaction_timestamp BETWEEN t.transaction_timestamp - INTERVAL '60 MINUTES' AND t.transaction_timestamp
   ) AS "lag_60_transaction_count",
   (SELECT SUM(revenue) / COUNT(DISTINCT vendor_id)
    FROM transactions_db
    WHERE transaction_timestamp BETWEEN t.transaction_timestamp - INTERVAL '60 MINUTES' AND t.transaction_timestamp
   ) AS "rolling_hourly_rate"
FROM transactions_db t
GROUP BY transaction_timestamp
ORDER BY transaction_timestamp;
```

Here is the EXPLAIN output:

```
 GroupAggregate  (cost=21989857.85..681893649752.90 rows=108423 width=56)
   Group Key: t.transaction_timestamp
   ->  Sort  (cost=21989857.85..22252785.49 rows=105171056 width=8)
         Sort Key: t.transaction_timestamp
         ->  Index Only Scan using timestamp_vendor_revenue_idx on transactions_db t  (cost=0.57..3663118.41 rows=105171056 width=8)
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=3143836.32..3143836.33 rows=1 width=8)
           ->  Index Only Scan using timestamp_vendor_revenue_idx on transactions_db  (cost=0.57..3142521.68 rows=525855 width=4)
                 Index Cond: ((transaction_timestamp >= (t.transaction_timestamp - '01:00:00'::interval)) AND (transaction_timestamp <= t.transaction_timestamp))
   SubPlan 2
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=3145150.96..3145150.97 rows=1 width=32)
           ->  Index Only Scan using timestamp_vendor_revenue_idx on transactions_db transactions_db_1  (cost=0.57..3142521.68 rows=525855 width=10)
                 Index Cond: ((transaction_timestamp >= (t.transaction_timestamp - '01:00:00'::interval)) AND (transaction_timestamp <= t.transaction_timestamp))
```

That being said, this query is taking an impossibly long time to run (8+ hours - ran it overnight and it was still running this morning).

I have a composite index created on transaction_timestamp, vendor_id, and revenue but running time is still outrageously high.

When I do run this query on a subset of the data (I have a sample table that contains one day of the data), the query returns in 2.1 seconds.

I'm pretty much completely green to optimizing databases and queries, so the fact that I can return this query on one day of data in 2.1 seconds leads me to believe that there's something I can do to make this query run in a reasonable amount of time for the main database.

Please let me know if there's any other information that I've left out.

Sample data, query and output here: http://rextester.com/AOKNT5900

Comment: Can you provide your `CREATE TABLE` to see the index?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza did you think of sending all data to GPU so it can do things quicker if it is computationally intensive?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik No, Im saying 100 millions table query doesnt need 8 hours.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza 100mm is millions. The index was created after the table was created - simply this:
    `CREATE INDEX timestamp_vendor_revenue_idx ON transactions_db (vendor_id, transaction_timestamp, revenue)`

Comment: even if the index was created after the table, you can get the `create table`  script from pgAdmin.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Here's sample data [http://rextester.com/SOBO41131](http://rextester.com/SOBO41131)

Comment: Also please include that in your question and add the desire result you expect with that data.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I looked into window functions, but atleast in PostgreSQL it doesn't appear that I can use a window function to slice rows by an interval. I believe I added the desired output in the image included in my question. I will add the sample data.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza updated code to add more examples per your request: [http://rextester.com/WBAC28692](http://rextester.com/WBAC28692)

Comment: I mean you now can use the rextexter to show the data + current query + actual result. And new we can suggest a new query and that query should generate same result.  I will remove my comments, and you update the question. http://rextester.com/AOKNT5900

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sorry never used rextester before, didn't know how it works.

Comment: 30 columns seems rather large. What is in there?

Comment: @wildplasser - lots of transactional data. I'm only focused on the 3 columns for this query - does that affect performance if I'm only looking at 3 columns?

Comment: Yes. The engine can only fetch+process+store whole rows, so your (I/O +) buffers will be swamped with stuff you don't actually need. (30 columns could also indicate lack of normalisation)

Comment: @wildplasser Oh. Did not know that.The data isn't redundant but could be separated into different categories/tables. That being said, sounds like it would be a massive speedup to create a table containing just the three columns in question.

And I realized that is probably horrible best practices, this is for a personal project on my own machine. I'm more concerned about getting this to work over "prod-proofing" things

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select t1.transaction_timestamp
, count (t1.*) transactions
, count(distinct t1.vendor_id) vendors
, sum(t1.revenue) / count(distinct t1.vendor_id) hourly_rate

from transactions_db t1 join transactions_db t2 
    on t1.transaction_timestamp > t2.transaction_timestamp
    and t1.transaction_timestamp < t2.transaction_timestamp + INTERVAL '61 MINUTES' 

group by t1.transaction_timestamp
```

Plus, unless you really need the entire database, filter on the transaction_timestamp and / or vendor_id

Comment: I also think I did.

Comment: Every get so focused on the logic that you forget the syntax?  I do.

Comment: Sorry If Im too intrusive. I think the group by should be over `t2.transaction_timestamp` I wish have a sample data to test it better :/

Comment: @DanBracuk Hi Dan - I want the entire database - trying to see trends over time for all transactions and vendors.

I'm confused at what your join statement is trying to accomplish - it looks like you're trying to join on the timestamp where t1 > t2 but then t2+1 hour > t1 which I don't understand.

What I'm trying to accomplish is say you have a given timestamp - let's say 01:00:00. I want a count of all transactions at 01:00:00, count of unique vendors that had a transaction between 00:00:00 and 01:00:00, and the average revenue per vendor between 00:00:00 and 01:00:00

Comment: The join should give you all the t1 data for the previous 60 minutes, which is what you say you want.

Comment: yes, but the problem is the group by. Same data can appear in different groups

Comment: @DanBracuk I tried running your query on my sample table (56k rows) - took 17 minutes and still didn't come back. I'll try to figure out what went wrong with it.

Comment: Dont run the 56k try it on rextester demo first. So you can compare with your current query

Answer (score 0):

This version provide the same result as your current query. I have to separate the calculations in two parts and then join at the end. Check both explain and let me know.

The key in the second query is create a subquery to have every timestamp as a group, and then join to get every revenue in that group.

```
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT transaction_timestamp 
       FROM transactions_db) t1
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/ZAP25192)**

```
WITH transaction_total as (    
    SELECT transaction_timestamp,
           COUNT (transaction_timestamp)  AS "total"
    FROM transactions_db t
    GROUP BY transaction_timestamp
), lag_60 as (
    SELECT  t1.transaction_timestamp, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT t2.vendor_id) as lag_60_transaction_count,
            SUM(revenue) / COUNT(DISTINCT t2.vendor_id) AS "rolling_hourly_rate"
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT transaction_timestamp 
           FROM transactions_db) t1 
    join transactions_db t2 
      on t1.transaction_timestamp <= t2.transaction_timestamp + INTERVAL '60 MINUTES'
     and t1.transaction_timestamp >= t2.transaction_timestamp
    GROUP BY t1.transaction_timestamp
)    
SELECT T1.transaction_timestamp,
       T1.total,
       T2.lag_60_transaction_count,
       T2.rolling_hourly_rate
FROM transaction_total T1
JOIN lag_60 T2
USING (transaction_timestamp)
ORDER BY T1.transaction_timestamp;
;
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Juan, good work - looks like it cut the total cost in half. I'll try running it but still worried about total time - might be a problem that I simply can't avoid due to the size of the data.

Comment: well, you can run it on yearly batch. Also you need check the `explain analyze` again. And you have to check the option `explain (analyze, buffers)` to see how is using the memory. Did you increase `work_mem` in your postgresql server?

Comment: I few days ago I face a similar [**problem**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902019/can-i-use-parallel-for-with-sql-commands) also millions of records. Instead of calculate  the query `1 to 10.000.000` I create one app in C# and that send query to postgress in batchs ... like `{1,10000}, {10001,20000}{20001,30000}` postgres can run multiple small query at once faster than a big query (I'm talking 20x faster). Also 9.6 has [Parallel Query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/parallel-query.html) so maybe you dont need it, but again you can check the explain plan.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I need to step out for an hour or so, I'll take a look at this when I get back.