# How do I insert multiple rows with a foreign key using a CTE in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to do a bulk insert transaction but I'm not too sure how to do this using CTEs or a more efficient method.  This is what I have so far:

```
with bulky as (
    insert into products (title, description, price) 
                  values ('Dope product 1', 'Buy diz', 9.99), 
                         ('Dope product 2', 'Buy diz', 8.99), 
                         ('Dope product 2', 'Buy diz', 7.99) 
                  returning id
) 
insert into product_metadata (product_id, sales_volume, date) 
                       values (???, 80, '2017-03-21'), 
                              (???, 50, '2017-03-21'), 
                              (???, 70, '2017-03-21');
```

The problem with my CTE is I don't know how to get the individual ids from the first insert statement to be inserted to their corresponding records for the second statement which has the 'product_id' foreign key.

How would I construct the statement to make it work?  I'm open to alternative solutions that offer a more efficient method to achieve the same result.

Comment: Edit your question and show the rows that you want inserted into the second table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff These are the rows I want insert into the product_metadata table: (ID FOR 'Dope product 1', 80, '2017-03-21'), (ID FOR 'Dope product 2', 50, '2017-03-21'), (ID FOR 'Dope product 3', 70, '2017-03-21').  Would your proposed answer work if you do the join on the title (i.title = v.title)? You're not referencing the id from the first insert so I'm not sure if it'd work

Comment: Jamaal:  @Gordon is doing the `JOIN` on the title (i.title = v.title) the problem is you cant have two of the same items on the first insert. I did a solution for solve that but is really messy. My suggestion insert product and metadata one by one.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza The problem with the one by one insert is it's too slow if you have a lot of data!

Comment: I dont know why you mean slow. I can insert 30k records in 5 seconds. Add some paralelism to your app.

Comment: This is an example with [**Parallel.For**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41902019/can-i-use-parallel-for-with-sql-commands) in C#

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Those are good suggestions, except I'm not using c# and I'm running on a single thread

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is a reasonable interpretation of what you want to do:

```
with i as (
      insert into products (title, description, price)
          values ('Dope product 1', 'Buy diz', 9.99),
                 ('Dope product 2', 'Buy diz', 8.99),
                 ('Dope product 3', 'Buy diz', 7.99)
          returning *
     ) 
insert into product_metadata (product_id, sales_volume, date)
    select i.product_id, v.sales_volume, v.date
    from (values ('Dope product 1', 80, '2017-03-21'),
                 ('Dope product 2', 50, '2017-03-21'), 
                 ('Dope product 3', 70, '2017-03-21')
         ) v(title, sales_volume, date) join
         i
         on i.title = v.title;
```

The basic answer is "use `returning *` and use a `join` to get the values".  I needed to change the titles so they are unique.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My guess is there is `product_id` autonumeric in `products` that is why he is `returning id`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . I always call that CTE `i`.  I missed that I left in the OP's original name.

Comment: Really helped me in my case. switched the nested value statement for a with statement using the previously returned inserted ids. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is even when you get the id from the first insert using  `returning id` there is no way you can use it to insert on the same order, because set in db  are by *definition unsorted*.

I did the exercise to match your requirement, but you should rethink your requirement because this is very tricky. Specially the part where you need a field to know the order for metadata.

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/JPX8613)**

1. You insert and get the id, in this case you get `{1,2,3}` but you can get `{31,32,33}`
2. Now using row_number you order that result by `id` and asign an rn to know the insert order `{1,2,3}`
3. Now your `metadata` also need some field so you know the order. In this case I create a field `insert_order` to match the order in which you are inserting. `{100,200,300}`
4. Also create a rn for `metadata`
5. Finally you can join both tables because you know the order of both.

.

```
with prod as (         
    insert into products (title, description, price) 
                  values ('Dope product 1', 'Buy diz', 9.99), 
                         ('Dope product 2', 'Buy diz', 8.99), 
                         ('Dope product 2', 'Buy diz', 7.99) 
                  returning id
), prod_order as (
       SELECT id, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
       FROM prod
), metadata as (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (order by insert_order) as rn
    FROM (values (100, 80, '2017-03-21'::timestamp),
                 (200, 50, '2017-03-21'::timestamp), 
                 (300, 70, '2017-03-21'::timestamp)
          ) t (insert_order, sales_volume, date) 
)    
INSERT INTO product_metadata
SELECT po."id", m."sales_volume", m."date"
FROM prod_order po
JOIN metadata m 
  ON po.rn = m.rn;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Your solution looks like it works but I don't think it'd handle the scenario where ids of the products table and row_number() are out of sync.  For example if you delete a few rows in the products table and the ids now have this sequence: 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, it doesn't seem like joining on row_number would work in this case, or maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Yes, that handle, first the new id from insert are always in sequence. But even that ...  you dont use that value to match... you use the rn you get from `row_number()` to do the match. And that go from `1..n`, the problem is you need to add the insert order for the metadata some how. Maybe if your date have `seconds` you could use it.