# How to get child table's foreign key to have same value as parent's primary auto-increment key

Tags: postgresql

I have created these two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Purchase(
purchaseID SERIAL,
custName VARCHAR(30) NOT null,
PRIMARY KEY (purchaseID));

CREATE TABLE PurchasedItem(
purchaseID INT,
itemNo INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (purchaseID, itemNo),
FOREIGN KEY (purchaseID) REFERENCES Purchase(purchaseID));
```

Next I wish to insert data into both tables, with the purchaseID foreign key of purchased item having the same value as the purchaseID Serial from Purchase table.

I am using a PostgreSQL client called PSequel. I tried setting AUTOCOMMIT to off first in the client so I could have the two INSERT statement in the same transaction, however the client didn't recognise "autocommit", so I tried it in the terminal and I think it worked... anyway, these are the two INSERT statements I tried.

```
INSERT INTO Purchase(custName) VALUES ('Lendl');
INSERT INTO PurchasedItem(purchaseID, itemNo) VALUES (DEFAULT, 111);
commit;
```

However I get an error:

```
ERROR: null value in column purchaseID violates not-null constraint.
```

this is referring to the PurchasedItem's purchaseID as in running the first INSERT statement by itself it works. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lastval()`

```
INSERT INTO Purchase(custName) VALUES ('Lendl');
INSERT INTO PurchasedItem(purchaseID, itemNo) VALUES (lastval(), 111);
commit;
```

Alternatively query the underlying sequence directly:

```
INSERT INTO Purchase(custName) VALUES ('Lendl');
INSERT INTO PurchasedItem(purchaseID, itemNo) 
VALUES (currval('purchase_purchaseid_seq'), 111);
commit;
```

Or if you don't want to rely on the automatic naming of the sequence, use `pg_get_serial_sequence` to get the sequence associated with the column:

```
INSERT INTO Purchase(custName) VALUES ('Lendl');
INSERT INTO PurchasedItem(purchaseID, itemNo) 
VALUES (currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('purchase', 'purchaseid')), 111);
commit;
```

For more details see the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

Comment: These all work perfectly :) is there any advantage to using one or the other?

Comment: @IvanLendl `lastval()` will only work if nothing else happens in your transaction between the two inserts. Otherwise all three of them work the same - it's a matter of personal taste

Comment: what if i wanted to put in an attribute that wasn't a sequence? then how would i get that value from one table to the other?

Comment: @IvanLendl: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33414552/330315) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7391090/330315) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42941006/330315) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21386772/330315)

Comment: So are CTE's the only watch to achieve this?

Comment: do these solutions, apart form lastval(), retrieve the autogenerated key in the same transaction? is it possible that it could get mixed up with another transactions id that's happening at the same time?

Comment: @IvanLendl: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) "*currval: Because this is returning a session-local value, it gives a predictable answer whether or not other sessions have executed nextval since the current session did*"

Answer (score 2):

`DEFAULT` will work for `SERIAL` as it sets default value for column. So

```
INSERT INTO Purchase VALUES (DEFAULT,'Lendl');
```

should work. But `PurchasedItem.purchaseID` has no default value set, so it it tries to  insert `NULL` (and null is not in referenced column yet), so it fails.

try:

```
INSERT INTO Purchase(custName) VALUES ('Lendl') RETURNING purchaseID;
```

you will see the value of inserted `purchaseID`, use it in next query:

```
INSERT INTO PurchasedItem(purchaseID, itemNo) VALUES (_the_value_above_, 111);
commit;
```

If you want it to be used without interactivity, use `DO` block with `returning purchaseID into _value`

*update*:

or cte, smth like

```
WITH i AS (
  INSERT INTO Purchase(custName, orderedDate) 
  VALUES ('Lendl', '2016-09-28') 
  RETURNING purchaseID
)
insert into PurchasedItem
select i.purchaseID,'smth',3
from i
```

Comment: how do you access _the_value_above_ as purchaseID? I am running this in a postgres client by the way: psequel. unsure how to use that returning purchaseid in the next statement.

Comment: I also don't understand the last part, with the DO block. How does that work?

Comment: returning purchaseID will show the value as if you were selecting, so just copy paste it