# Insert multiple values with foreign key Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having trouble figuring out how to insert multiple values to a table, which checks if another table has the needed values stored. I am currently doing this in a PostgreSQL server, but will be implementing it in PreparedStatements for my java program.

user_id is a foreign key which references the primary in mock2. I have been trying to check if mock2 has values ('foo1', 'bar1') and ('foo2', 'bar2').

After this I am trying to insert new values into mock1 which would have a date and integer value and reference the primary key of the row in mock2 to the foreign key in mock1.

mock1 table looks like this:

```
===============================
| date  |  time    |  user_id |
| date  |  integer |  integer | 
|       |          |          |
```

And the table mock2 is:

```
==================================
| Id      |  name   |  program   |
| integer |  text   |  test      |
```

Id is a primary key for the table and the name is UNIQUE.

I've been playing around with this solution https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key

However, I haven't been able to make it work. Could someone please point out what the correct syntax is for this, I would be really appreciative.

EDIT:

The create table statements are:

```
CREATE TABLE mock2(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
   name text NOT NULL,
    program text NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE mock1(
   date date,
   time_spent INTEGER,
   user_id integer REFERENCES mock2(Id) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Hey, apologies for the bad explanation. I'm not adding anything I was just trying to show the layout of the database. I've changed the + with | and added the create statements. Thank you,

Comment: Please [edit] your question and also add the code that doesn't work. The linked question seems to perfectly answer your question.

Comment: There are also multiple duplicates here on SO: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33414552) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391090)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42941006)

Comment: I just noticed the answer was staring me in my face, I wasn't using the primary/foreign keys to my advantage. I've posted my own answer to the question. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found an answer to my own question.

```
WITH ins (date,time_spent, id) AS
( VALUES
    ( '22/08/2012', 170, (SELECT id FROM mock3 WHERE program ='bar'))
)  
INSERT INTO mock4
   (date, time_spent, user_id) 
SELECT 
    ins.date, ins.time_spent, mock3.id
FROM 
  mock3 JOIN ins
    ON ins.id = mock3.id ;
```

I was trying to take the 2 values from the first table, match these and then insert 2 new values to the next table, but I realised that I should be using the Primary and Foreign keys to my advantage.

I instead now JOIN on the ID and then just select the key I need by searching it from the values with `(SELECT id FROM mock3 WHERE program ='bar')` in the third row.